# While Program wont loop or do prompt four

Tags: c++

My program should prompt the user for their first and last name, then prompt the user with a list of things they can do, and then run what the user wants to do.

However, it does not loop, or do anything, for the prompt about creating a right triangle. It should loop back to the beginning of the program and continuously prompt the user for a number to go through again, unless prompted otherwise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using  namespace std;

int main()
{
    //****** Variable section *********
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int selectionPrompt;
    double squareRootNum;
    double squareRootResult;
    int x;
    int y;
    int completePower;
    double numGrade;
    int tInput;
    bool doAgain = true;

    //****** Welcome Section **********
    //Output welcome header      
    cout  <<"*********************************************\n";
    cout  <<"* Programming Fundamentals 1 course project *\n";
    cout  <<"*********************************************\n";
    //prompt user for first name and store   
    cout << "What is your first name: " << endl;
    cin >> firstName;
    //prompt user for last name and store   
    cout << "What is your last name: " << endl;
    cin >> lastName;
    //Output a welcome message to the user    
    cout << "welcome to my course project " << firstName <<"!" << endl;
    cout  <<"*********************************************\n";

    // Prompt user for a number

    cout << "Enter 1 to Calculate Square Root\n";
    cout << "Enter 2 to Enter X to the Y power\n"; 
    cout << "Enter 3 to Convert Numerical GPA to a Letter Grade\n";
    cout << "Enter 4 to create a right triangle.\n";
    cout << "Enter 0 to Exit\n";
    cout << "Enter Your Request: " << endl; 

    cin >> selectionPrompt;

    //If the user enters 1
    while (doAgain) {
        if (selectionPrompt == 1) {
            cout << "Enter a number to calculate the Square Root: " << endl;
            cin >> squareRootNum;

            //run sqrt

            squareRootResult == sqrt(squareRootNum);

            cout << "The Square Root of 25 is 5" << endl;
            doAgain == true;
        }
        //If the user enters 2
        else if (selectionPrompt == 2) {
            cout << "Enter a number X to raise to the Y Power\n";
            cout << "Enter X: " << endl;
            cin >> x;

            cout << "Enter Y: " << endl;
            cin >> y;

            completePower = pow(x, y);
        
            cout << x << " to the " << y << " power is " 
                 << completePower << endl; 
            doAgain == true;
        }
        else if (selectionPrompt == 3) {
            cout << "Enter Your numerical Grade: ";
            cin >> numGrade;

            if (numGrade >= 3.7) {
                cout << "Letter grade is a A";
            }
            else if (numGrade >= 2.7) {
                cout << "Letter grade is a B";
            }
            else if(numGrade >= 1.7) {
                cout << "Letter grade is a c";
            }
            else if (numGrade <= 1.3) {
                cout << "You are Failing.";
                doAgain == true;
            }
            else if(selectionPrompt == 4){
                cout << "Please input the triangle height: ";
                cin >> tInput;

                for (int i; i <= tInput; i++) {
                    for (int f = 1; f <= tInput; f++) {
                        cout << "*";
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                    cout << "\n";

                    doAgain == true;
                }
            }
            else {
                doAgain == false;
            }
        }
        return 0;  
    }
}
```

I do not know where I am going wrong, as I have added the prompt to make the bool false. I also just added on the fourth prompt, but just added in another `else if` for the fourth prompt.

Comment: What does the debugger say? (side note, your teacher is bad. In C++ we dont declare variables on function start and we dont put the std namespace on top).

Comment: Fixing your brace indentation, there's something really weird going on around `else if(selectionPrompt == 4){`

Comment: Minor point: `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied, so reading from `std::cin` flushes `std::cout` before looking for input. You don’t need those `std::endl`s.

Comment: This code would be much easier to write and to read if each of those operations was in its own function. `main` would then prompt for the selection and call the appropriate function.

Comment: The wildly unpredictable indentation in the original edit of this question was the cause of the confusion.  When indentation is clear and consistent, typos like this won't happen.

Comment: FYI, in C++ you can declare variables closer to where they are first used.

Comment: BTW, a good programming habit to start is to initialize your variables when you declare them.  When you declare a variable, it is assigned the value that was in memory before; some random value.

Comment: The `switch` statement is really good for processing menu selections.

Comment: You are also not initializing `i` in the triangle loop, which causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else if(selectionPrompt == 4)` is at the wrong level.  It is attached to the `if (numGrade ...)` block inside of the `if (selectionPrompt == 3)` block, because you are missing a closing `}` after the `else if (numGrade <= 1.3)` block before reaching `else if(selectionPrompt == 4)`:

```
else if (selectionPrompt == 3) {
    ...
    if (numGrade >= 3.7) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    else if (numGrade <= 1.3) {
        ...
    }
    // <-- MISSING A } HERE!
    else if(selectionPrompt == 4){
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

It should look like this instead:

```
else if (selectionPrompt == 3) {
    ...
    if (numGrade >= 3.7) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    else if (numGrade <= 1.3) {
        ...
    }
} // <-- ADD THIS!
else if(selectionPrompt == 4){
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Other problems I see are:

- your `if (numGrade ...)` blocks are missing output for grade `D`, as you are not accounting for `numGrade` being between `1.3 - 1.7`.
- you have several places in the code where you are using the `==` comparison operator where you meant to use the `=` assignment operator instead.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice the missing bracket! As for the '==' I added them last minute because I was unsure if the bool was not being prompted and jumping back to the top.